# Add VAT option for each product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, vat

How i can Add **VAT** option for **each product**. There are some with **VAT** and others with no **VAT**. And if **VAT** it should show on the order for the customer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento products have **tax classes** you need for every tax percentage one tax class.

BE CAREFUL! if you ship in multiple countries and have this country tax, you need a tax class for every product group which has a tax percentage in one or the other country.

Example (only VAT and not 100% sure this is correct in regards of content):
Germany:

- cinema ticket 19%
- Books 7%
- cigaretes 19%

**This looks like you need two tax classes.**

Austria:

- cinema ticket 13%
- cigaretes 20%
- books 10%

**But if you ship to austria you need three!**

After creating all the tax classes you need to define all tax rates for each country.

All customers get a tax class too. So you can differ between the ones who pay tax (customers from your country normally) and thos who don't e.g. companies from EU.

Then you need to map all tax classes to the tax rates.

[More on this here, with screenshots! Thanks to hostknox](http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/managing-taxes)

Comment: Ahhh EU tax rates <3 Great answer!

Comment: thank you for your response but i have one question , when i create a tax class and define all steps needed , can i set **VAT**  fixed value  not in % ?

Comment: No. But Magento supports Fixed Product Taxes.  I have no clue how this works: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/tax/tax-fixed-product.html

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt thank you in advance , i've solved.

Comment: I can confirm (to the best of my knowledge) that the AT tax rates are correct to this date.